# Why some parts of this code are red in VS Code?

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn JavaScript. I have this script which should generate composite numbers in my separate HTML file, but I don't really understand why some parts are highlighted red when I moved script to `.js` file.
[image]

So my question is why there are some parts that are highlighted and how I'm suppose to write it correctly? I need to `use strict` in this script. I know that when using *strict mode* I need to declare variables, objects etc.

Comment: What is `if(var num == 1)` supposed to achieve in the first place?

Comment: Did you hover over it and see what the linter is complaining about?

Comment: If you mousehover over those red bits VSCode will tell you what the issue is. It's not clear why `checkComposite` is immediately invoked since the function that calls it is a) _inside_ that function b) never invoked itself.

Comment: Why do you have `<script>` in a `.js` file?

Comment: It's all syntax mistakes, Please watch some JS tutorials & get back to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you are working in a javascript file.

remove the script tags

you only need script tags in other file types like html etc

```
function checkComposite(num) {
    var arr = [];

    if( var num == 1 ) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( var num == 2) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var x = 2; x < num; x++) {
        if(num % x == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 function compositeNumbers() {
    num = Number(document.getElementsById('number').value);
    for(var j = 1; j < num; j++) {
        if(checkComposite(j)) {
            arr.push(j);
        }
    }
    document.getElementsById('result').innerHTML = arr;
 }
```